# Anonymize data elements Delimited File

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a Delimited file in which I would like to anonymize First Name, Last Name and Middle Name from SQL Table. Please suggest any good approach using c#.

Delimited File:

```
Spec: SegmentName*Qualifier*Id*LastName*FirstName*MiddleName
NM1*IL*12345*JOHN*SMITH*A
NM1*IL*87912*BRYAN*JOE*A
NM1*IL*932578*STEVE*BILL*A
```

SQL TABLE:

```
Id, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName
12345, Perry, Ellis, G
87912, Jerry, Fish, M
932578, Gary, Todd, T
```

Desired Result Delimited File:

```
NM1*IL*12345*Perry*Ellis*G
NM1*IL*87912*Jerry*Fish*M
NM1*IL*932578*Gary*Todd*T
```

Comment: "All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard." Do you mean you just want to change the names, such as from John Smith to Ellis Perry, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused as well...why not just post as "anonymous" or something....or just "name hidden" ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to update your question illustrating what you've attempted to date otherwise it just looks like you're asking people to do all your work for you.

Comment: Just need to swap names from SQL to File.

Comment: @middaparka, I am looking for suggestions not asking you to do my work.

Comment: Do you want random names or a known replacement? If you want random names just go find a list of random names, there are hundreds across the internet. Then a simple join using ROW_NUMBER or such would give you random names that change each time you run it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\text.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connStr = "Enter Your connection string here";
            string SQL = "Enter your SQL here like Select * from table1";

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adapter.Fill(dt);

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join("*", row.ItemArray));
            }

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to know the domain of applicability to answer the question. What does "anonymize" mean to you? You already have an `id` field so you could simply not include the names and that would be "anonymous" in some sense. But it's not anonymized to those who have access to the `id` numbers. In that case you might want to replace the id, lastname, and firstname all with a randomized Guid identifier using `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Of course, such data is still probably not fully anonymized. Combining the remaining data with outside datasets could still be used to reconstruct identities. Sometimes research protocols require fake data be injected into the dataset to prevent people from being able to statistically reconstruct identities from otherwie "anonymous" data, for example.

There's no silver bullet for anonymization, and don't assume that the names are the only identifiers in your data.